# browse output of find command with cd and ls commands

Tags: shell, files, find

I have a file that contains the output of `find` called on a directory on another computer. I'd like to browse the file/directory structure with commands `cd`, `ls`, etc. as if it would be in my file system. How can I do this?

Example of my find output file

```
/a0/a1/
/a0/a1/a2
/a0/a1/a2b
/a0/a1/a2b/a2b1.txt
/a0/a1/a2b/a2b2.txt
```

In my case, all paths are absolute. I have around 755,000 entries in the full file.

Comment: I have added an example of my find output file to the description.

Comment: Excellent. (1) Is `a2` an empty directory or a file? (More importantly, how should the file browser respond for this situation?) (2) Why does the directory name `a1` end with `/` but the directory name `a2b` doesn't?

Comment: (1) Good question. I'm not sure if it is even possible to distinguish file and directory by the output of find. I can not tell if `a2` is a directory or a file. (2) Another good question, but this time I know the answer. It depends on how you pass the path you'd like to search to `find`. If you call `find /a0/a1` it doesn't end with `/`, but it does if you call `find /a0/a1/`. However, no subdirectory ends with `/`.

Comment: I counted 755066 entries using `wc -l find.output`.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to create a dummy file structure of all file paths in my current directoy that I can browse afterwards:

```
cat find.output | sed -r 's/^\/(.*)$/"\.\/\1"/' | xargs mkdir
```

- `find.output` is my file
- I use `sed` to make absolute paths relative and quote them (in case they contain spaces)
- `xargs` is used to create a directory for each path

However, I would be happy about a solution that does not touch my real file system.

Comment: Since you're already using GNUisms (`-r`): `cut -c2- < find.output | xargs -rd '\n' mkdir -p --` (would also avoid problems with filenames containing double quote characters; note that the newline characters will always be a problem as the format of your found.output file doesn't allow for them).

Comment: Do this on a tmpfs filesystem.

Comment: @Gilles Thanks. If you or someone else writes an answer that describes how to use `tmpfs` in my use case, I will accept it as my favorite answer.